# Is connect.facebook.net the only source to get the JS SDK from?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I'm having an issue with firewalls/proxies blocking the 'connect.facebook.net' url, simply because it's not from the facebook.com domain, and the admin are unwilling to unblock that address.

Is there another source, or an authorized way to download the SDK and source it locally?

Answer (score 0):

That would be a very bad idea in my opinion as the SDK changes weekly or sometimes more often, if you cache an old copy of the SDK you'll get inconsistent behaviour. 
If your firewall grants access to facebook.com you should also be granting access to facebook.net

Comment: I have no control over the firewall/proxies and the admin have naively denied by request to unblock connect.facebook.net. I'm hoping there are alternatives... ;(